# EmbeddedKafkaBroker set properties throws NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/zk/EmbeddedZookeeper

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When we initialize EmbeddedKafkaBroker with:

```
EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, 1, environment.getProperty("producer_topic"), environment.getProperty("consumer_topic"));
embeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet();
```

The second line throws:

```
method 'embeddedKafkaBroker' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/zk/EmbeddedZookeeper
```

**EDIT - Added the GAV format of the dependencies**
We have seen many answers regarding dependencies mismatch, so we checked ours. We can't put all the poms that we use, so here are the relevant dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your POM; [Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:kafka%2Fzk%2FEmbeddedZookeeper) says that class should be in `kafka_2.11`. (Note for future reference that in diagnosing something like this, you should include the entire GAV rather than omitting the group.)

Comment: Why are you putting in an exclusion for `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` and then explicitly re-including it? Presumably you're doing the same for `spring-boot`. That's *probably* not the problem, but it's weird.

Comment: You are somehow missing the kafka-test jar; it's normally pulled in transitively by spring-kafka-test.

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow missing the kafka_2.11-2.2.0-test.jar; it's normally pulled in transitively by spring-kafka-test.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

BTW, scala 2_12 is recommended with the 2.x clients.

Also, your `kafka-streams` jar must be the same version as `kafka-clients`.

See the [Spring for Apache Kafka reference manual appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#deps-for-21x) for how to override the dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```